# Exit WLST and continue execution of batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, weblogic, jython, wlst

I've a batch file that does the installation of weblogic, during the setup it will invoke wlst to run some jython scripts.

The execution runs fine, but just does it doesnt exit the wlst and continue on with the rest of the bat file execution.

This is where I invoke wlst in the bat file.

```
echo ... Setting Path for WLST
start /wait /B %middleware%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd > /nul 2>&1

echo ... Executing WLST to create domains
%middleware%\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd %current_dir%\createdomain.py
```

In the py script, `exit()` is called, and im stuck at this message prompt, nothing goes on after.

```
Exiting Weblogic Scripting Tool
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `wlst.cmd` command script with command **CALL** like this:

```
call "%middleware%\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "%current_dir%\createdomain.py"
```

Same thing for the `setWlsEnv.cmd`. You should not start it with the **START** command as this runs the command script in a different command process.

Not right is:

```
start /wait /B %middleware%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd > /nul 2>&1
```

Right would be:

```
call "%middleware%\wlserver\server\bin\setWLSEnv.cmd" >nul 2>&1
```

Please note removed `/` left to `nul`.

A last thing, calling `setWLSEnv.cmd` before `wlst.cmd` is not required because `wlst.cmd` does this itself.

Comment: hey this worked. thanks! anyway to print the stacktace from executing py scripts?

Comment: Do you mean printing a stack trace when the python code fails and throws an exception  ?

Comment: Yes, i only managed to do that using start /wait command, cant find anything about call.

Comment: You can try something like this :  `import sys, traceback  
try  
...  
except:  
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)`